# How to show parameter in plot

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I want to show alpha = 2, beta = 2.
That is, parameter

```
beta_plot <- function(a, b, ...) {
  x <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.02)
  y <- dbeta(x, shape1 = a, shape2 = b)
  plot(x, y, main = expression(paste(alpha, " = ", a,"  ", beta, " = ", b)),  xlab = NA, ylab = NA, ...)
}
beta_plot(2, 2)
```

but 
It shows

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `bquote`

```
beta_plot <- function(a, b, ...) {
 x <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.02)
  y <- dbeta(x, shape1 = a, shape2 = b)
  plot(x, y, main = bquote(alpha~" = "~.(a)~" "~beta~" = "~.(b)  ),
              xlab = NA, ylab = NA, ...)
 }

beta_plot(2, 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! this is that I want. By the way,  bquote's description : An analogue of the LISP backquote macro. What's mean?